# Inconsistent results in iterative calculation of circular reference in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, circular-reference

I have a circular reference with embedded VLOOKUP function which I solve using the iterative calculation.
I have two adjacent columns that have same logic behind the circular reference and the iterative calculation is checked.

However the results that I get are not consistent: when I change the amount in the right column it gives different results depending on whether the previous value was higher or lower from the benchmark number.

Link to the workbook:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ju59oknnerklf7/Circular_reference_with_VLOOKUP.xlsx

Any ideas as to why is that?
Many thanks.

Comment: The blog posting system identified as a link just a part of it due to space character in the file name.

Replaced with another link without spaces:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0rpqnran0kyd7qz/circular_reference_with_VLOOKUP_non_consistent.png

Answer (score 0):

Very difficult to know without seeing the spreadsheet. The formulas you put for example doesn't seem to be consistent with the results you have in column D and E. The range of H5:K19, with a col_index_num of 3, should select the Spread, not the Rating.

Then because you haven't defined a TRUE or FALSE value in your Vlookup, it's defaulting to TRUE. Assigning the [range lookup] variable to TRUE will default to the closest lowest value it matches and in this case you should have a table_array of G5:J19.

Comment: Thanks for the pointing out that I put the link to screenshot rather than to workbook.
I fixed the top post.
In any case, the link to workbook is as follows:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ju59oknnerklf7/Circular_reference_with_VLOOKUP.xlsx

Comment: Which cell are you are you changing? The Level of Debt (E5), EBIT (D2), or RFR(D3). I think you need to explain this a little more. I'm getting the same results from both columns D & E, when I change the debt level. Can you post an example of it not working?

Comment: Column D, namely D5:D9 is a becnhmark.
I change the E5.
You can set for instance the E5 value to 30, then you get 
Implied rating A2/A and Kd = 5%.

Then set the E5 to 55 (just like the value of D5, benchmark).
Implied rating = B3/B-, kd= 11%.

So far, so gut. D5 = E5 -> D9 = E9.

Now, change the E5 to 70. As a result, E9 = Ca2/CC.

NOW, the punchline. Set E5 back to 55 (the benchmark value).
E9 (Implied rating) = Caa/CCC.

Comment: It looks like the calculation of E9 depends on previous calculations.
If I change the value in E5 from below (30->55) then I get one result.
If I change the value in E5 from above (70->55) then I get another one.